# Parsing a json tree with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have got GSON as a JSON parser in Java, but the keys aren't always the same.
For example. I have the following JSON:

```
  {
       "message":"....", 
         "categories_sorted": [
            {
              "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000": [
                {
                  "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655443333": [
                     {
                      "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655448964": []
                     }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655443334": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440023": [
                {
                  "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655442344": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
```

I need to parse this tree "categories_sorted". My Java POJO object:

```
public class CategoryPOJO {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;

    @SerializedName("categories_sorted")
    @Expose
    private JsonArray sortedCategoryItems;

.......
Getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I found the approximate versions of decisions, but they do not work in my case
Link: [link] (https://gist.github.com/patrickbaumann/897492)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do GSON Deserialiser method for this [ReferenceLink](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer). You have to custom like this just for example :

```
@Override
public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
                        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        return new CategoryPOJO(
            json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsInt(),
            json.getAsString(),
            json.getAsInt(),
            (CategoryPOJO)context.deserialize(json.getAsJsonPrimitive(),
            CategoryPOJO.class));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

see jsonschema2pojo.org resource for getting POJO classes (select GSON and JSON options)

Comment: I have seen this resource before.
But it is not suitable to me because my keys are dynamic